# Unable to parse this dateString into an NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to parse

```
2013-01-23T22:46:29.564Z
```

into an NSDate with:

```
NSDate *date = [GeneralHelper getDateFromDateString:expiryDateASStr];
if(date != nil) {
    printf("\n PARSED DATE %s", [date.description UTF8String]);
} else {
    printf("\n failed to parse");
}
```

but it is failing, how can I get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: what's the `.564Z` part in your date?

Comment: Could you post the code for `getDateFromDateString`? It's tough to tell whats wrong without seeing the code thats isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `NSDateFormatter`

```
NSString * dateString = @"2013-01-23T22:46:29.564Z";
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS.SSS'Z'"];
NSDate * date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Answer (score 4):

Like @Gabriele said, using a `NSDateFormatter` is the way to go. The following will work for you, including the date format:

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[df setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS.SSS'Z'"];
NSLog(@"%@", [df dateFromString:expiryDateASStr]);
```

Do NOT use the capital Ys "YYYY" unless you want the year in "Week of Year" based calendars. Most use cases "yyyy" is the correct way to specify the year.

Comment: thanks I updated my answer, with a proper date format. You're right about  the YYYY, I mistyped that. Also I didn't figure out that .464 were milliseconds, I was thinking about some kind of weird timezone!